# I can't run a code on the console on spyder

Tags: error-handling

I've already defined a ran the code def myname():
print("My name is Bill") and it runs on the console. But when I try to re-run it on the console, it says "NameError: name 'myname' is not defined".

It keeps showing the same thing only when write and run the code on the console.

Comment: Please explain how exactly you run this. Is this a script? Do you run it in Python's interpreter in interactive mode? See [ask].

Comment: I run it on Spyder IDE. (I'm relatively new to programming). I'm following a course material on Coursera, and can't seem to find answers to my question there.